# Triple scripts for analysis

Tags: subscripts, superscripts, scripts, music

I am doing the music harmonic analysis. 
There are plenty of symbols that must be added and there are need for:

- underscript
- triple sub/super scripts:

[image: example image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\stackscript[1]{\tiny\sffamily\shortstack{#1}\normalsize}
\newcommand\textunderset[2]{$\underset{\textsf{#1}}{\textsf{#2}}$}
\def\xline{\rule{0ex}{1.5ex}\rule[.7ex]{9ex}{.1ex}}
\def\noline{\phantom{\xline}}
\def\blank{\phantom{0}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\stackscript{$>$\\\blank}\textunderset{5}{Mt}\stackscript{8\\6\\4}%
  \stackscript{\xline\\\xline}\stackscript{5\\3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDITED to add sans serif numerals, per barbara beeton's suggestion.  I'll have to think more on how to make the numerals/lines closer together, as was also noticed by barbara (and myself).

Comment: using sans serif numerals to match the "text" style would improve the appearance.  also, it looks like the drawn lines in the question image might be a bit closer together than yours.  (you've got the baseline of the `4 -- 3` line the same as the original image, which i suspect a lot of people might overlook.  that's good.)